# BitmapFactory.decodeFile returns null

Tags: android, bitmap, bitmapfactory

I'm going to compress image with `Bitmap.compress()` method.

But when I get `Bitmap` using `bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile()` I get a `null` object, and the method didn't thow any exception.

Here's my code

```
public static File compressImage(String imagePath) throws IOException {

    // Get bitmap
    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath, options);

    // Get bitmap output stream
    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, byteArrayOutputStream);

......
```

When the code runs at the last line I get a `NullPointerException` :

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.graphics.Bitmap.compress(android.graphics.Bitmap$CompressFormat, int, java.io.OutputStream)' on a null object reference
```

Then I run my code in debug mode, it turns out I got a `null` object from `BitmapFactory.decodeFile` method.

The parameter `imagePath` is

> /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20160610_195633.jpg

which seems ok.

This piece of code works well in another activity, but when i copy it to a async thread which I attempt to compress and upload images, it crashed. Is there any possibilities that this is because the async thread thing? Or something else I didn't notice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the following from your code:

```
options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
```

From the documentation of `inJustDecodeBounds`:

> **If set to true, the decoder will return null** (no bitmap), but the
>   out... fields will still be set, allowing the caller to query the
>   bitmap without having to allocate the memory for its pixels.

`inJustDecodeBounds` is useful to load large `Bitmap`s efficiently, since you can read their dimensions without having to allocate the memory for them, although it has no purpose in your code.

Answer (score 0):

This answer applies if you are using your phone connected via USB to debug your code.  My phone indicates Android version 6.0.1.

I read all of the posts about setting my "Uses-permission" fields and my code still didn't work.  I found, however, that I needed to go into my device under "settings->device->applications->application manager" and then click on the application I was debugging and navigate to "Permissions" and manually enable the requested permissions.

The following permissions must be in your AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```